# Database of Diacritics

Tags: data-request, language

I'm working on a project to map Unicode English characters to diacritic characters in Javascript. When the user enters e.g. "doner" the search engine should also find e.g. "döner". So it should be completely diacritics insensitive.

Is there a single source where absolutely all (trustful) diacritics are listed?

Example of the conversion:

```
var DIACRITICS = {
    'a': '[aÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāąĄ]',
    'c': '[cÇçćĆčČ]',
    'd': '[dđĐďĎ]',
    'e': '[eÈÉÊËèéêëěĚĒēęĘ]',
    'i': '[iÌÍÎÏìíîïĪī]',
    'l': '[lłŁ]',
    'n': '[nÑñňŇńŃ]',
    'o': '[oÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøŌō]',
    'r': '[rřŘ]',
    's': '[sŠšśŚ]',
    't': '[tťŤ]',
    'u': '[uÙÚÛÜùúûüůŮŪū]',
    'y': '[yŸÿýÝ]',
    'z': '[zŽžżŻźŹ]'
};
```

I need to be sure that the list is complete, so just pointing out a code repository that uses diacritics isn't enough for me – unless it references the sources.

Comment: The python unidecode package does this, maybe have a look at the source: https://github.com/iki/unidecode

Comment: @Swier I've had a look at the repository, but didn't find anything about diacritics. Could you please provide a reference to this specific file?

Comment: I've never actually had a look into the source, just sort of assumed the answer would be there. But it seems to take the bytecode and convert that to letters in all the files in the unidecode folder, I don't know how though, but it might be worth it to contact one of the contributors.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string/

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Thanks for your hint. But, these people don't named the sources of their diacritics, so I can't be sure that the list is complete.

Comment: @dude Some of the answers there do normalisation without lists.  The list-based approached is problematic anyway because there are arbitrary diacritic combinations (eg ǘ).  Note also that a simple mapping ie simply dropping the diacritic is not always ideal (eg Turkish 'ü' is ASCII-normalised to 'u', but German 'ü' to 'ue').

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Thanks for your help. I'm aware of the normalization and umlauts issue. However, I definitely need to mape ASCII characters with diacritics. I just need a single source that I can be sure the list is complete.

Comment: The best way I know to generate an exhaustive list is to decide your rules, and then write code to iterate through all unicode characters - by codepoint ie converting int to char - in the blocks that matter to you, adding characters to your mapping based on your rules.  I have seen it done in Python, but not Javascript, but the list will of course be useful to you either way.

Comment: One more interesting edge case:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I.

Comment: You may want to ask the linguists who created Doulos Sil a font designed to be IPA compatible and support orthography and diacritics for documenting languages - http://software.sil.org/doulos/

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer The turkish "i" (without the dot) can also be simply added to the "i" mapping as well as diacritic combinations ("ǘ" -> "u"). I don't see any problem regarding this.

Comment: I can echo what @A.M.Bittlingmayer says - just because the pixels looks similar doesn't mean the character would linguistically map to the nearest ASCII character.

Comment: @philshem 1. Can you give me an example where this isn't the case? 2. What do you suggest?

Comment: 1. ü to ue in German, and then as a distinct letter in Hungarian, Karelian, Turkish, Uyghur Latin, Estonian, Azeri, Turkmen, Crimean Tatar, Kazakh Latin and Tatar  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C

Comment: 2. are you working on a linguistic problem or a ASCII character problem?

Comment: @philshem I've updated my use case.

Comment: @dude, sorry, but the doner/döner/doener example just examplifies the difficulty of natural language processing (NLP). In german, O-umlaut maps to OE and in other languages not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doner_kebab "In German, it is spelled Döner Kebab, which can also be spelled Doener Kebab if the ö character is not available". If you want to make a search-tool, then you should be using some sort of fuzzy matching anyway, probably with [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Comment: @philshem When searching for "doner" from an UK point of view, also "döner" should be found (as they don't have this chracter on their keyboard and "döner" is the correct word in other languages – while it's "doner" in UK). So, the mapping should just make it possible for users to find things with diacritics they can't type or don't know. Umlauts seems to be the only case where we can't simply map one character to another. But that shouldn't be a huge problem, as this can be done using a regular expression. So why don't we focus on the database of diacritics rather than on the principle?

Comment: @dude Đ maps to dj or th, depending on the language https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%91 , the point is that similar looking characters don't necessary map back to the same ASCII character.

Comment: @philshem Thank you for pointing this example out. Would be great if the database of diacritics contains such information too.